# Confusion in calculating number of steps for various algorithms?

Tags: data-structures

I've been learning data structures and algorithms from a book, in which it compares time efficiency in terms of number of steps taken by various sorting algorithms. I'm confused as to what we define as one step while doing this.

So while counting no. of steps we consider the worst case scenarios. I understood how we come up with the no. of steps for bubble sort. But for selection sort, I am confused about the part where we compare every element with the current lowest value.

For example, in the worst case array, lets say 5,4,3,2,1, and lets say we are in the first pass through. When we start, 5 is the current lowest value. When we move to 4, and compare it to 5, we change the current lowest value to 4.

Why isnt this action of changing the current lowest value to 4 counted as a swap or an additional step? I mean, it is a step separate from the comparison step. The book I am referring to states that in the first passthrough, the number of comparisons are n-1 but the no. of swaps is only 1, even in worst case, for an n size array. Here they are assuming that the step of changing the current lowest value is a part of the comparison step, which I think should not be a valid assumption, since there can be an array in which you compare but don't need to change the lowest current value and hence your no. of steps eventually reduce. Point being, we cant assume that the no. of steps in the first pass through for selection sort in the worst case is n-1 (comparisons) + 1 (swap). It should be more than (n-1) + (1).

I understand that both selection sort and bubble sort lie in the same classification of time complexity as per big O methodology, but the book goes on to claim that selection sort has lesser steps than bubble sort in worst case scenarios, and I'm doubting that. This is what the book says: https://ibb.co/dxFP0

Comment: That image url doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So, how could the selection sort do more than ome swap in a pass? The definition of a selection sort pass is "find the smallest value and swap it to the correct place".

Comment: @rici so when you are finding the smallest value, you go through the elements and compare it with the current lowest value. If you find a new lower value, you assume that as the new lowest value. You would do this by using some variable which stores the index of current lowest value and hence this variable's value would get changed whenever you find a new lower value. This isn't exactly a swap but this definitely contains steps which we shouldn't ignore. Like for example in insertion sort, the removal and insertion of the element which is getting compared, is also accounted for in # of steps.

Comment: it's a lot less work than a swap (one store rather than three). That's sufficient to make it faster. In practice, it is a register store (as is one of the swap stores) and register operations are much faster than touching memory.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in these kinds of exercises you’re interested in whether the algorithm is O(1), O(n), O(n^2) or something higher. You’re generally not interested in O(1) vs O(2) or in O(3n) vs O(5n) because for sufficiently large n only the power of n matters.

To put it another way, small differences in the complexity of each step, maybe favors of 2 or 3 or even 10, don’t matter against choosing an algorithm with a factor of n = 300 or more additional work

Comment: I know that, but the book goes on to claim that the max no of steps for selection sort are less than that for bubble sort, which I doubt. I am not talking about time complexity in terms of Big O. The book is comparing bubble sort and selection sort which lie in the same classification as per big O.

Comment: I think a better explanation is that, a single swap is more heavy in no. of steps than step of changing the current lowest value. In any case that book seems very uncareful in its explanations

Comment: Apparently I'm having trouble understanding your question, sorry.  Is the key this part: "Why isnt this action of changing the current lowest value to 4 counted as a swap or an additional step?"  When doing large N operations, it's the stores (swaps) that cost time.  Changing a value in a register is so quick that you don't bother to count it.  (This step-counting approach has only mixed relevance in modern processors, where cache locality makes a huge difference)